# Use of this in bash script.

Tags: linux, bash, shell

What is the `if [[ -z $1 ]]` statement exactly checks here ?

Whenever I run it outputs like this :

> [root@localhost ~]# sh script.sh
>
> No argument is given

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then

echo "No argument is given"


elif [ "$1" == "testfile" ] ; then

echo "Right argument is given"

else

echo "Wrong argument is given"

fi
```

Comment: When will people finally start to simply read the documentation of the tools they use?

Answer (score 3):

See `man bash`:

> ```
> [[ expression ]]
> ```
>
> Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression

and further below

> ```
> -z string
> ```
>
> True if the length of string is zero.

Answer (score -3):

The $# variable will tell you the number of input arguments the script was passed.

Or you can check if an argument is an empty string or not like:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo "No arguments supplied"
fi
```

Comment: Nothing in the question asks about the number of arguments passed, and `$1` can be the empty string without `$#` being 0.